# How is this if statement working

Tags: php

```
<?php if ($result->getSellerLocation()) : ?> <?php endif;?>
```

Hi

Can someone please explain what is the code above is doing? I know how the normal if else works.. what is the final : at the end

Comment: It's just shorthand syntax commonly used in templates

Comment: Can you explain to me how it is workig or better yet just convert it to a normal if else pleassse :(

Comment: It's all documented here - http://php.net/manual/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered in the PHP manual

Comment: it is a normal if else. you are just breaking out of php to write html presumably.

Comment: @KaiQing or in this case, a single space character

Comment: Thanks thank you thank you @Phil. I am saved for this friday

Comment: @Phil Only off-topic if seeing an unexpected colon means the phrase "control-structures-alternative-syntax" springs to mind. It doesn't for most people, and syntax constructions like this are usually hard to google.

Comment: @DarrenCook Closing as *"Off Topic"* doesn't remove the question or comments. Others will be able to find it and be directed to the PHP manual. There's just no need for an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the alternate syntax for if statements. We usually use it when there is interceding HTML to be output in the final result.

This method is said to increase readability.

For example:

```
<?php if ($foo == $bar) : ?>
    <p class="conclusion"> $foo does equal $bar </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can also use `else if :`.

This works essentially the same as:

```
<?php if ($foo == $bar) { ?>
    <p class="conclusion"> $foo does equal $bar </p>
<?php } ?>
```

or:

```
<?php
    if ($foo == $bar) {
       echo '<p> $foo does equal $bar </p>';
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps!